# Convert avr assembly program to hex

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

I need to convert an avr assembly program to hex manually. I know I should use the instruction opcode but I don't know how to use it. For example, the syntax of the `LDI` instruction is :

```
LDI Rd,K
```

And the opcode is : `1110 kkkk dddd kkkk`

So for those `kkkk` should I add them together? If so the result will be more than 4 bits so how can I do it?

This is the code :

```
LDI R16,HIGH

OUT SPH,R16

LDI R16,LOw

OUT SPL,R16

LDI r24,$2b

STS $0069,r2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need more context: Is this homework? How are you planning to convert, manually or by software? Do you have already looked for an instruction table for your AVR? If so, what makes you stumble? And so on, and so on... Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]".

Comment: I edited it  thanks for the note

Comment: I think that's one 8-bit field split into two parts in the encoding, just because the designers chose it that way, probably so the destination register number field is in the same place as other instructions.  An `ldi` instruction has room for an arbitrary 8-bit value.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, let's look how this is done.

First, get an instruction table. I found this one as the first hit in a simple web search by "avr instruction table":

[AVR Instruction Set Manual @ Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf)

`LDI Rd, K` with `d` as the register number and `K` as the immediate value to be loaded into that register, is described in chapter 73 as coded as `1110 KKKK dddd KKKK`.

We need to look up the meaning of the letters. Well, the documents is silent about this. Uh-oh, bad documented, we need another source.

One of the other hits looks promising:

[AVR instruction set - all opcodes @ Lyons42](http://lyons42.com/AVR/Opcodes/AVRAllOpcodes.html)

Just one or two clicks, and we find that the higher nibble (4-bit half) of `K` goes into the first byte of the opcode. And the lower nibble goes into the second byte.

For example, `LDI R23, 150` will have `d = 23 - 16 = 7` (minus 16 because only R16 to R31 are supported, and so 16 is an offset), and `K = 150 = 0x96`. The opcode becomes `1110 1001 0111 0110` or `0xE976`.

All next instructions can be translated the same way.

*Note: a much more simpler solution is to use an assembler and to look into its listing. But this might be cheating. ;-)*

Answer (score 1):

> And the opcode is : 1110 kkkk dddd kkkk
>
> So those kkkk should i add them together ?

Because the documentation doesn't say, then the right approach is to use the most obvious encoding, which is to say place the low 4 bits of 8-bit K in the later kkkk and the upper 4-bits in the earlier kkkk.

However, you can (and should) double check this yourself by using an assembler with this instruction and a constant (say 0x5A) where you can tell what's going where — then either look at the assembly listing output from the assembler, or, disassemble using an objdump tool, or look at the machine code instruction in a debugger.

More broadly, you should consider designing experiments to find answers to this kind of question.

---

Looks like it might go the other order, low order 4-bits in first kkkk and high order in last kkkk.